# Function is not defined in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you help me?

I'm using a script in one file to call other function in another file, but I'm getting *function is not defined*. So I've start searching to fix this way but I didn't get any positive results. Check my code below:

**index.html**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        lAs = new loadAsync();
    }, 900);
});
```

**js/plugins.js**

```
function window.loadAsync() {
    $(".loadAsync").each(function(index, element){
        $(element).attr("src", $(element).attr("data-src"));
    });
}
```

So, what should I do to fix this problem? Thank you.

@edit:

```
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
```

I've already wrote this in *index.html*

Comment: `function loadAsync() {`

Comment: What is this `function window.loadAsync()` way of declaring functions ? You should be getting a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: I saw it on another thread in stackoverflow, but with it or not, the error persists: _Uncaught ReferenceError: loadAsync is not defined_

Comment: If it's still not defined, then there's some problem that isn't represented in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your syntax is wrong. An identifier may not have a `.` in it. Just use `loadAsync` and it'll be global unless you've nested it in another scope.

You can also make the jQuery more efficient by calling `.attr()` with a callback instead of using `.each()`.

Finally, it seems unlikely that you actually want to use `new` to invoke the function. I changed the code below to simply pass it as the callback to `setInterval`. I also declared the `lAs` variable properly.

```
function loadAsync() {
    $(".loadAsync").attr("src", function(){
        return $(this).attr("data-src");
    });
}
```

---

```
var lAs;
$(document).ready(function(){
    lAs = setInterval(loadAsync, 900);
});
```

---

And of course all this can be done easily without jQuery.

```
function loadAsync() {
  for (const el of document.querySelectorAll(".loadAsync")) {
    el.src = el.dataset.src;
  }
}
```

---

```
var lAs;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    lAs = setInterval(loadAsync, 900);
});
```

Comment: Downvoted because you most likely downvoted my answer while essentially repeating the same thing in yours. If the reasoning is different, please do inform me and I will remove my downvote.

Comment: Thanks. IMO, things would be so much better if they just allowed votes to be public.

Comment: @Crazy_Train Yep, downvotes certainly should be harder, I bet that there are certain people who don't even view question details and just downvote based on bad titles, therefore throwing half the new questions into an abyss, but I hear that they are making the site from friendly towards newcomers.

Comment: @doubleOrt also I didn't downvoted you too, I haven't level to perform this action.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I'm getting this warning/error now: http://prntscr.com/jjqqur

Comment: I don't know why, but inserting type="text/javascript" in <script> tag makes the script work! Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `function window.whatever() {}` is wrong (could you include the link of the SO thread where you saw that being used ?).

Since you are getting an error even without that, please make sure that:
1. `loadAsync` is declared in the global scope in the `plugins` file.
2. You are including `js/plugins.js` correctly. Go on and insert `foo bar;` in `js/plugins.js` and then check if you get a `SyntaxError` (while including it before the other JS file), if you don't, you are not correctly including it.

Comment: I saw yesterday, I don't have the link right now. Sorry.